# AJAX Dropdown Extender Question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, dropdownextender

Ok, so I got my extender working on a default.aspx page on my website and it looks good.  I basically copied and pasted the code for it into a user control control.ascx page.  When I do this I completely loose the functionality (just shows the target control label and no dropdown, even upon hover).  Is there any reason why it doesn't work in a custom user control inside a masterpage setup?

Edit:
Didn't quite do the trick.  Any other suggestions?
Its in a master page setup, using eo web tabs (I tried it inside the tabs and outside the tabs but on the same page as the tabs, to no avail), and its in a custom user control.  Think there are dependency issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but I had the same problem with the autocomplete extender and determined that the server-side function could not be in the user control, but needed to be on the page (or in a webservice, I guess). Once I moved the function, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently EO has compatibility issues with MS Ajax Control Toolkit.  http://www.essentialobjects.com/Forum/Default.aspx?g=posts&t=1319
I guess I'll leave this question open to see if anyone figures out some sort of workaround.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of looking I found a call to a modal popup extender .show() in the code behind.  After commenting it out everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the DocType.  Here is what I have found useful

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" >
```

Place this in your user control (or the page that uses it) and all should be well.  I had a similar problem with a collapsible extender and this worked for me.

Edit: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825/uncollapsible-collapsiblepanelextender) to my question for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm all that functionality on the loose! careful you don't lose it (sorry!)

Are you using something like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) (firefox plug-in) so you can see what ajax calls the page is trying to make? If it is making the call but the server is behaving oddly then you will see the error there too. IE users maybe able to use [dev toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en).